# Boundedness of the functional such that $F(e_n)=1/n$ (Functional analysis beginner exercise)

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-writing

Let $F$ be the functional on $l_2$ such that: $$F(e_n)=1/n,$$ where $\{e_n=(0,0,…,0,1,0,…)\}$ is the canonial basis of $l_2$. I wish to prove that $F$ is continuous. Since $F$ is continuous iff it is bounded in the unitary neighbourhood of zero, I try to show this last property is true. We have: $$|F(x)|=|F(x_1e_1+…x_ne_n+…)|=|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x_n}{n}| ≤\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|x_n|}{n}$$ with: $$||x||=(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|^2)^{1/2} ≤ 1.$$ But then i do not know how to proceed. Any hints? Is it possible that the boundedness on the basis automatically implies the boundedness in the whole space?

Comment: Simple application of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\ell^2$ is a Hilbert space, every element $x\in \ell^2$ can be represented as $x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_ne_n$, where $\{c_n\}$ is a sequence of scalars such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|c_n|^2=||x||_{\ell^2}^2<\infty$.

Now notice that
\begin{align*}|F(x)|&=\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{c_n}{n}\right|\\&\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|\frac{c_n}{n}\right|\\&\leq\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty|c_n^2|\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{1/2}&& (Cauchy-Schwarz) \\&=K||x||_{\ell^2}
\end{align*}
Where $K=\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{1/2}$. Thus, $F$ is bounded and hence continuous.